# Javascript array shuffle shouldn't output two next to eachother

Tags: javascript, arrays, shuffle, charat

I got an array which is filled with some letters. **See example below.**
First I want the array is getting shuffled. Well I found the most famous shuffle for it called the **Fisher-Yates** shuffle.

Now I want that when it outputs, e.g. the **F2** shouldn't be next to **F** nor **F'**.
Same goes for the other. **D** shouldn't be near to **D2** or **D'**.

It should output e.g.:
R B2 U F L F D2 .... and so on.

and not: R **B2 B'** L F D2 ...

Any help, suggestions? I know I should check the first chars with `charAt()` but I'm not an expert in that function.

**Javascript**

```
function shuffle(sides) {
    var elementsRemaining = sides.length, temp, randomIndex, last;
    while (elementsRemaining > 1) {
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * elementsRemaining--);
        if (randomIndex != elementsRemaining) {
        temp = sides[elementsRemaining];
        sides[elementsRemaining] = sides[randomIndex];
        sides[randomIndex] = temp;
        }
    };
}

  return sides;
}

var sides = ["F ", "R ", "U ", "L ", "D ", "F2 ", "R2 ", "U2 ", "L2 ", "D2 ", "F' ", "R' ", "U' ", "L' ", "D' "];
shuffle(sides);
$('#scramble').html(sides);
```

Comment: Are you saying that you want to guarantee that there will be no consecutive items in a shuffled array?

Comment: Yes, correct. That's what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can shuffle, check your constraint and repeat if constraint not met. Your method for checking constraint can be

```
var passesConstraint = function(sides) {
    for(var i = 0; i < sides.length - 1; i++) { 
        if (sides[i][0] === sides[i+1][0]) { 
            return false;
        }
     } 
    return true;
}
```

You need not do charAt(), strings can be accessed by [] notation too.

```
shuffle(sides)
while (!passesConstraint(sides)) {
   shuffle(sides)
}
```